# Angle of object relative to the camera and video? Video and camera output different

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I am wondering if I have got my thinking write about this, I have calibration done for my camera and now I want to get the angle of detected objects relative to the camera only on the x-axis, the horizontal.
I am thinking I can put some grid lines across the image at known pixel values and match those with know real world distances and calculate the angle per pixel that way, knowing the distances of the triangles.  Starting at the centre of the image 0 degrees, and as we move towards the right +X degrees and towards the left -X pixels.

Assuming this is a correct way to go about it, for some reason the video I'm working with was recorded at 704x576 pixels, but when I plug the camera into my computer to work with it's 640x480 pixels and it's the same camera that made the recordings.  I assume this will affect my results somewhat, with the calibration and definitely with the angle per pixel measurement that I want.  I am working with OpenCV in C++, I am wondering if there's a way/function to adjust the screen size for when I call up the camera to 704x576 and if I then do my measurements at this size can I get a somewhat accurate angle per pixel measurement?  Or do I need to do something else?

I'm still figuring my way around camera geometry and openCV, and any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier than you think. Say your camera has 60.0 deg horizontal field of view (FOV). Than each pixel along X axis is just 60.0/640 deg. You can easily calculate FOV by considering a right triangle with sides formed by a focal length vector and half of the screen width:

FOV = 2*atan(640/2, focal) where focal length is in pixels

for example, for focal=500 pixels 
FOV = 2*atan(640/2, 500) = 1.14rad = 65.2deg

One thing to keep in mind is that focal length changes proportionally with screen resolution. For example, if you calculated focal=500 based on 640x320 image, then for 320x160 image focal=250.